# apple store app with backend generated content

Tags: ios, iphone

We are investigating if it is possible to publish application which has auto generated content/validations(forms mostly), which is provided by the backend.

The idea is that the backend call would supply all required information  to the application on startup and application would generate ui, wire up validations etc where needed.

Im trying to find if this kind of application will pass apple store review process but so far I cant find definite answer to this question.

Any info regarding this would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think you can. Base on the response from server, you catch cases in your code. But it will be a huge json response. If you want to do some small configure, you can research about `Firebase Remove Configure` (https://www.raywenderlich.com/188230/firebase-remote-config-tutorial-for-ios-2)

Comment: @bola : make sure when u submit app to review point it to live server if possible and make sure server sends proper data :) Dynamic app like these have no restrictions imposed by apple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, **this is possible. This will pass Appstore review also**. The reason for this is, in our app we have similar kind of requirement. Where we build a form which will be generated based on the JSON response coming from backend. We have multiple textfields, and it's validations everything from backend. It's successfully passed the review. But the only thing I see difficult is implementing if from front-end-side. For the basic options like textfields, it's easy. Where as for things like picker-view to select option will be extra over-head. This is entirely depends on what kind of form you want to build.

Comment: If this helps you. Please accept the answer so that it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

Apple would in most cases always refuse to add any iOS App that has a full UI that could be generated remotely on each launch. Also it present a huge security risk for all your App users. This is something Apple also takes into account. Plus how can they then actually know that what they have approved won't change the moment it's live on the App Store. So yeah ...

They have extensive reading on these things and while it might not say anywhere "word for word" what they would accept or reject you can read it between the line also as they state them selves " *as a Supreme Court Justice once said, “I’ll know it when I see it”. And we think that you will also know it when you cross it.* "

First of, look at these pages from Apple Developer.

- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/
- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/
- https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/
- https://developer.apple.com/design/
- https://developer.apple.com/design/tips/

I hope it helps